# Bayesian model comparison vs Bayesian Model criticism

Tags: r, bayesian, mixed-model, inference

What is the difference between Bayesian model comparison vs Bayesian model criticism? Can someone explain with an example?

Answer (score 0):

Model comparison *compares* - you have at least two models, and you're deciding which one fits the data better.

Model criticism doesn't - you have a *single* model, you're just trying to see if it breaks on some new data.

A classical analogue to model comparison would be rejecting a null hypothesis (only you don't implicitly favor any model as the null).

A classical analogue to model criticism would be something like cross-validation.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how cross validation differs from null hypothesis testing ?

Comment: Err... what? These are so unrelated I don't even know where to start...

Answer (score 0):

Bayesian model comparison refers to comparing two or more models; Bayesian model criticism refers to evaluating the fit of a single model (without a competing model to compare with).

Regarding your second question about hypothesis testing, the use of Bayes factors has been likened to hypothesis testing. Bayes factors is a form of model selection or model comparison.